# pdf form to csv python or similar

Tags: python, xml, csv, pdf, converters

I've got a bunch of pdf forms created with Adobe formscentral - they are all formatted the same and I want to extract the data in the fields to a CSV file. I'm (getting) a little familiar with python and have tried a few libraries to extract the text via the XML tags. I've got to the point where I'm way out  of my depth though:(

I've managed to read the PDF with 'pdfquery' and/or 'beautifulsoup' but can't find a simple tutorial anywhere to help my parse the pdf to a csv/excel. I've searched SO and can't seem to find anything totally relevant. The XML tree I've managed to extract gives me the tags for field names (see below) but not sure how to proceed from here. Has anyone had any experience of this kind of operation or able to point me in the direction of any tutorials.

Any help gratefully received!

Thanks

Marty

```
    <pdfxml ModDate="D:20140414114502+03'00'" CreationDate="D:20140407143830-04'00'" Producer="Adobe FormsCentral 889953 S" Creator="Adobe FormsCentral 738134">
  <LTPage bbox="[0, 0, 595.27, 841.89]" height="841.89" pageid="1" rotate="0" width="595.27" x0="0" x1="595.27" y0="0" y1="841.89" page_index="0" page_label="">
    <LTRect bbox="[0.0, 0.0, 595.27, 841.89]" height="841.89" linewidth="0" pts="[[0.0, 0.0], [595.27, 0.0], [595.27, 841.89], [0.0, 841.89]]" width="595.27" x0="0.0" x1="595.27" y0="0.0" y1="841.89">
      <LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.015, 732.217, 133.831, 745.798]" height="13.582" width="99.816" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.015" x1="133.831" y0="732.217" y1="745.798"><LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.015, 732.217, 133.831, 745.798]" height="13.582" index="1" width="99.816" x0="34.015" x1="133.831" y0="732.217" y1="745.798">Name of organisation: </LTTextBoxHorizontal></LTTextLineHorizontal>
      <LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.015, 707.554, 128.739, 721.135]" height="13.582" width="94.724" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.015" x1="128.739" y0="707.554" y1="721.135"><LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.015, 707.554, 128.739, 721.135]" height="13.582" index="2" width="94.724" x0="34.015" x1="128.739" y0="707.554" y1="721.135">Type of organisation: </LTTextBoxHorizontal></LTTextLineHorizontal>
      <LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 631.024, 136.667, 657.37]" height="26.347" index="3" width="102.642" x0="34.025" x1="136.667" y0="631.024" y1="657.37"><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 643.789, 136.667, 657.37]" height="13.582" width="102.642" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="136.667" y0="643.789" y1="657.37">Number of employees/ </LTTextLineHorizontal><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 631.024, 112.269, 645.166]" height="14.143" width="78.244" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="112.269" y0="631.024" y1="645.166">members (male): </LTTextLineHorizontal></LTTextBoxHorizontal>
      <LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 581.871, 136.667, 620.462]" height="38.592" index="4" width="102.642" x0="34.025" x1="136.667" y0="581.871" y1="620.462"><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 606.881, 136.667, 620.462]" height="13.582" width="102.642" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="136.667" y0="606.881" y1="620.462">Number of employees/ </LTTextLineHorizontal><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 594.116, 134.963, 608.259]" height="14.143" width="100.938" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="134.963" y0="594.116" y1="608.259">members aged 18-35 </LTTextLineHorizontal><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 581.871, 64.076, 596.014]" height="14.143" width="30.051" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="64.076" y0="581.871" y1="596.014">(male) </LTTextLineHorizontal></LTTextBoxHorizontal>
      <LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 557.728, 112.861, 571.31]" height="13.582" width="78.836" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="112.861" y0="557.728" y1="571.31"><LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 557.728, 112.861, 571.31]" height="13.582" index="5" width="78.836" x0="34.025" x1="112.861" y0="557.728" y1="571.31">Location/Address </LTTextBoxHorizontal></LTTextLineHorizontal>
      <LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 494.974, 138.371, 533.045]" height="38.071" index="6" width="104.346" x0="34.025" x1="138.371" y0="494.974" y1="533.045"><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 519.463, 99.821, 533.045]" height="13.582" width="65.795" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="99.821" y0="519.463" y1="533.045">Type of waste </LTTextLineHorizontal><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 507.218, 138.371, 520.8]" height="13.582" width="104.346" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="138.371" y0="507.218" y1="520.8">management activities </LTTextLineHorizontal><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 494.974, 85.066, 508.555]" height="13.582" width="51.04" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="85.066" y0="494.974" y1="508.555">carried out: </LTTextLineHorizontal></LTTextBoxHorizontal>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the [lxml package](http://lxml.de/installation.html) as it has a very handy objectify module that makes parsing XML pretty trivial.

Here's an example that shows a few ways to extract data from the XML:

```
from lxml import objectify

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def parser(xml):
    """"""
    root = objectify.fromstring(xml)
    print root.LTPage.LTRect.attrib
    for item in root.LTPage.LTRect.getchildren():
        print item.tag
        print item.text
        print item.attrib
        print item.attrib["bbox"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml = """<pdfxml ModDate="D:20140414114502+03'00'" CreationDate="D:20140407143830-04'00'" Producer="Adobe FormsCentral 889953 S" Creator="Adobe FormsCentral 738134">
  <LTPage bbox="[0, 0, 595.27, 841.89]" height="841.89" pageid="1" rotate="0" width="595.27" x0="0" x1="595.27" y0="0" y1="841.89" page_index="0" page_label="">
    <LTRect bbox="[0.0, 0.0, 595.27, 841.89]" height="841.89" linewidth="0" pts="[[0.0, 0.0], [595.27, 0.0], [595.27, 841.89], [0.0, 841.89]]" width="595.27" x0="0.0" x1="595.27" y0="0.0" y1="841.89">
      <LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.015, 732.217, 133.831, 745.798]" height="13.582" width="99.816" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.015" x1="133.831" y0="732.217" y1="745.798"><LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.015, 732.217, 133.831, 745.798]" height="13.582" index="1" width="99.816" x0="34.015" x1="133.831" y0="732.217" y1="745.798">Name of organisation: </LTTextBoxHorizontal></LTTextLineHorizontal>
      <LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.015, 707.554, 128.739, 721.135]" height="13.582" width="94.724" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.015" x1="128.739" y0="707.554" y1="721.135"><LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.015, 707.554, 128.739, 721.135]" height="13.582" index="2" width="94.724" x0="34.015" x1="128.739" y0="707.554" y1="721.135">Type of organisation: </LTTextBoxHorizontal></LTTextLineHorizontal>
      <LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 631.024, 136.667, 657.37]" height="26.347" index="3" width="102.642" x0="34.025" x1="136.667" y0="631.024" y1="657.37"><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 643.789, 136.667, 657.37]" height="13.582" width="102.642" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="136.667" y0="643.789" y1="657.37">Number of employees/ </LTTextLineHorizontal><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 631.024, 112.269, 645.166]" height="14.143" width="78.244" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="112.269" y0="631.024" y1="645.166">members (male): </LTTextLineHorizontal></LTTextBoxHorizontal>
      <LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 581.871, 136.667, 620.462]" height="38.592" index="4" width="102.642" x0="34.025" x1="136.667" y0="581.871" y1="620.462"><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 606.881, 136.667, 620.462]" height="13.582" width="102.642" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="136.667" y0="606.881" y1="620.462">Number of employees/ </LTTextLineHorizontal><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 594.116, 134.963, 608.259]" height="14.143" width="100.938" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="134.963" y0="594.116" y1="608.259">members aged 18-35 </LTTextLineHorizontal><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 581.871, 64.076, 596.014]" height="14.143" width="30.051" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="64.076" y0="581.871" y1="596.014">(male) </LTTextLineHorizontal></LTTextBoxHorizontal>
      <LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 557.728, 112.861, 571.31]" height="13.582" width="78.836" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="112.861" y0="557.728" y1="571.31"><LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 557.728, 112.861, 571.31]" height="13.582" index="5" width="78.836" x0="34.025" x1="112.861" y0="557.728" y1="571.31">Location/Address </LTTextBoxHorizontal></LTTextLineHorizontal>
      <LTTextBoxHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 494.974, 138.371, 533.045]" height="38.071" index="6" width="104.346" x0="34.025" x1="138.371" y0="494.974" y1="533.045"><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 519.463, 99.821, 533.045]" height="13.582" width="65.795" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="99.821" y0="519.463" y1="533.045">Type of waste </LTTextLineHorizontal><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 507.218, 138.371, 520.8]" height="13.582" width="104.346" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="138.371" y0="507.218" y1="520.8">management activities </LTTextLineHorizontal><LTTextLineHorizontal bbox="[34.025, 494.974, 85.066, 508.555]" height="13.582" width="51.04" word_margin="0.1" x0="34.025" x1="85.066" y0="494.974" y1="508.555">carried out: </LTTextLineHorizontal></LTTextBoxHorizontal>
    </LTRect>
    </LTPage>
    </pdfxml>
      """
    parser(xml)
```

Note that I modified the XML to have proper ending tags. You might also find this tutorial useful:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/06/parsing-xml-with-python-using-lxml-objectify/